# Decrypting TLS Browser Traffic With Wireshark - Body is still encrypted

Tags: networking, ssl, wireshark

I was trying to reverse engineer a protocol using wireshark. I followed [this article](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/) and tried to decrypt TLS Browser Traffic using **SSLKEYLOGFILE** since decrypting using private key didn't work for me. Using **SSLKEYLOGFILE** seems to work. But only headers get decrypted. How do I make the body decrypted as well?

Note: The solution in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/389475/decrypting-ssl-traffic-in-wireshark-only-headers-get-decrypted) might not apply to my question because decrypting using public key doesn't support Diffie-Hellman ciphers. But I am not using private key to decrypt. Instead I am using **SSLKEYLOGFILE** which supports Diffie-Hellman ciphers. See [this article](http://joji.me/en-us/blog/walkthrough-decrypt-ssl-tls-traffic-https-and-http2-in-wireshark)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting SSL traffic in Wireshark. Only headers get decrypted](http://superuser.com/questions/389475/decrypting-ssl-traffic-in-wireshark-only-headers-get-decrypted)

Comment: **You can't.**  You would have to perform a Man-In-The-Middle attack in order to decode it.

Comment: What protocol are you trying to reverse engineer?  If it's something like http/2, it will have compressed frames inside the TLS records.

Comment: Edited my question with further info. I am trying to reverse engineer http/1.1. Is there any way to uncompress frames inside the TLS records? Forgive my ignorance. I am new to computer networking. @Adrien

Comment: is the client just a browser?  If so, you may be able to pipe it through a TCP plug that adds SSL on the upstream connection, then just wireshark plain old http between the browser and the TCP plug service.

Comment: What headers exactly are no longer encrypted? HTTP headers? In that case, you have succeeded. What you see now might simply be compressed (gzip or deflate).

Answer (score 1):

As Ramhound said, you need to do a man in the middle attack for decoding the message. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is a great tool to do that. And you don't need SSLKEYLOGFILE or anything like that.